# Flask testing exceptions raised at multiple layers(view & handler)

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am trying to write a unit test for my flask application. Here is the example application. I have a `view` defined to update books in the database.

```
from .handlers import update_book

@app.route('/update')
def books():
   # ....get params

   update_book(book_id,book_data)
```

`update_book()` raises an exception if no book with the given id is found.
`update_book()` raises an exception if there is some error in `book_data`.

Now my question is should I unit test both the `view` and `handler`? If I unit test my `view` the handler will automatically be tested?

Should I have both `test_update_book_handler()` and `test_update_book_view()` or will only `test_update_book_view()` be sufficient?

Comment: Unit test rule: every non-trivial function deserves own tests. So yes, you should be testing both `books()` and `update_book()`. You can mock out the latter when testing the earlier.